# Apache Camel upload email attachment to ftp

Tags: apache-camel

I'm using the following processor to fetch the first attachement of an email and upload it to a ftp-server.

**Route configuration**

```
<from uri="imaps://...
<to uri="ejb:java:global/Dms/MailProcessor"/>
<to uri="ftp://....
```

**MailProcessor**

```
@Named("MailProcessor")
@Stateless
public class MailProcessor implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

        exchange.getOut().setHeaders(exchange.getIn().getHeaders());

        Map<String, DataHandler> attachments = exchange.getIn().getAttachments();
        if (attachments.size() > 0) {
            for (String name : attachments.keySet()) {
                DataHandler dataHandler = attachments.get(name);

                // SET ATTACHMENT FILENAME TO OUTPUT FILENAME HEADER
                String filename = dataHandler.getName();
                filename = MimeUtility.decodeText(filename);
                exchange.getOut().setHeader("filename", filename);

                // SET INPUT ATTACHMENT TO OUTPUT BODY
                byte[] data = exchange.getContext().getTypeConverter().convertTo(byte[].class, dataHandler.getInputStream());
                exchange.getOut().setBody(data);

                // SET ONLY THE FIRST ATTACHMENT
                break;
            }
        }else{
            exchange.getOut().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody());
    }

}
```

This works in general, but it takes literally forever for "big" attachments. (half an hour for just a 5 mb attachment)

**Log**

```
TRACE [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations] (Camel (example) thread #119 - imaps://mail.example.com) Changing directory: upload
TRACE [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations] (Camel (example) thread #119 - imaps://mail.example.com) doStoreFile(ID-example-local-59752-1494841993139-21-11)
DEBUG [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations] (Camel (example) thread #119 - imaps://mail.example.com) About to store file: ID-example-local-59752-1494841993139-21-11 using stream: com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream@601a11dc
TRACE [org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations] (Camel (example) thread #119 - imaps://mail.example.com) Client storeFile: ID-example-local-59752-1494841993139-21-11
 -- long pause --
```

I've also tried to convert the attachment like this:

```
byte[] data = exchange.getContext().getTypeConverter().convertTo( byte[].class, dataHandler.getInputStream() );
exchange.getOut().setBody(data);
```

but this gives me the following:

```
2017-05-15 11:23:20,968 TRACE [org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter] (Camel (example) thread #133 - imaps://mail.example.com) Converting org.apache.camel.Processor$$$view63 -> org.apache.camel.Processor with value: Proxy for view class: org.apache.camel.Processor of EJB: MailProcessor
2017-05-15 11:23:20,968 TRACE [org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor] (Camel (example) thread #133 - imaps://mail.example.com) Using a custom adapter as bean invocation: Proxy for view class: org.apache.camel.Processor of EJB: MailProcessor
2017-05-15 11:23:20,990 TRACE [org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter] (Camel (example) thread #133 - imaps://mail.example.com) Converting com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream -> byte[] with value: com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream@28442828
2017-05-15 11:23:20,990 TRACE [org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter] (Camel (example) thread #133 - imaps://mail.example.com) Using converter: StaticMethodTypeConverter: public static byte[] org.apache.camel.converter.IOConverter.toBytes(java.io.InputStream) throws java.io.IOException to convert [class com.sun.mail.util.BASE64DecoderStream=>class [B]
2017-05-15 11:23:20,990 TRACE [org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper] (Camel (example) thread #133 - imaps://mail.example.com) Copying InputStream: java.io.BufferedInputStream@24b2cffb -> OutputStream:  with buffer: 4096 and flush on each write false
-- long pause --
```

Uploading to the ftp server using Filezilla works like a charm. Also when I use camel-ftp in another route ( triggered by a file upload ) the upload to the ftp server works pretty fast.
So I have a feeling that it's the conversion of the attachment which slows things down.

**Questions:**

Is my assumption correct and how can I speed things up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to use `<from uri="imaps://...&mail.imaps.partialfetch=false`.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2604843?start=0&tstart=0